# Python función recursiva. programando minijuego RPG

Tags: python, recursión

llevo unos días con este problema y no consigo dar con él.
Estoy programando un minijuego de un sencillo RPG a raiz de un cursillo de Udemy. He seguido indagando y creando nuevas funciones.

El problema viene cuando uso la función recursiva para solicitar que se elija 'item' cuando elegimos uno que esta agotado, 'quantity = 0'. Mi main.py llama a la función **check_item** ubicada en el archivo game.py. la cual elige y checkea.

```py
def check_item(self):
        self.choose_item()
        item_choice = int(input("     Choose Item: ")) - 1
        if self.items[item_choice]["quantity"] == 0:
            print(bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "\n" + "     None left..." + bcolors.ENDC)
            self.check_item()
        else:
            self.items[item_choice]["quantity"] -= 1
            return self.items[item_choice]["item"]
```

Todo es correcto mientras no elija un item con 'quantity' igual a 0. Cuando lo hago el error es el siguente en el main despues de recoger el resultado de la función **check_item** en la variable **item**.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jorge/PycharmProjects/battle/main.py", line 177, in <module>
    if item.type == "potion":
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type
```

la linea 177 dónde recojo el resultado de la función.

```
 elif index == 2:
            item = player.check_item()
            print(item)
            if item.type == "potion":
                ally_choice = player.choose_ally(players)
                players[ally_choice].heal(item.prop)
```

Ese **print(item)** me devuelve **None** en lugar de una posicion de la clase Item almacenada en el fichero inventory.py como si ocurre cuando escojo items con quantity > 0

Mas información del código:

```
# Items
potion = Item("Potion", "potion", "Heals 200 HP", 200)
elixer = Item("Elixer", "elixer", "Fully restores HP/MP of one party member", 9999)
hielixer = Item("Megaelixer", "elixer", "Fully restores HP/MP of all party members", 9999)
ether = Item("Ether", "ether", "Recover 100 MP", 100)
armordrink = Item("HeroDrink", "stats", "Increase Ally defense", 100)
grenade = Item("Grenade", "attack", "Deals 500 damage", 500)

player_items = [{"item": potion, "quantity": 20},
                {"item": elixer, "quantity": 3},
                {"item": hielixer, "quantity": 1},
                {"item": ether, "quantity": 3},
                {"item": grenade, "quantity": 3},
                {"item": armordrink, "quantity": 0}
                ]
```

Parece que cuando la función **check_item** hace uso de su capacidad recursiva da lugar a error.
Espero que sea información suficiente para ayudarme a resolver el problema. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando llamas a la funcion `check_item()` tienes dos opciones, que la cantidad sea 0 o no. Cuando la cantidad no es 0, haces un `return` del item, y luego en tu main.py compruebas si ese item es una pocion `if item.type == "potion":`.

El problema viene cuando la cantidad si que es 0 y no haces ningun `return`, por lo que la instruccion `item = player.check_item()` le asigna un valor a `item` de `None`. Al hacer la comprobacion de la pocion en este segundo caso, te da el error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'`, porque obviamente `None` no tiene el atributo `type`.

Para solucionarlo puedes:

- Antes de checkear que el tipo es pocion, comprueba que no es None,
- o en la funcion check_item() haz un return con la misma estructura que uno normal pero con los campos marcados como 'vacio' por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste a solucionar el problema y a entender el funcionamiento de la función recursiva!